# Link to load specific page of local PDF from Markdown document

Tags: pdf, github, markdown

I'm writing a Markdown document and want to make references back to specific pages in a local PDF document. I can achieve this with PDF documents on the web by appending `#page=<page number>` to the end of the URL. Is the an analogous way to do this with a local PDF file? I've got this Markdown document and the corresponding PDF in a repo on Github. I'd love to be able to examine the Markdown file on there and click on the links to the corresponding PDF and have the referenced page load. Appreciate any suggestions you may have!

Comment: Should be OK. Can provide the live repo code to test?